# WEB-INF not getting added to SpringBoot jar

Tags: spring, spring-boot, maven

I'm putting together a webapp using SpringBoot.

The REST part works fine, but the "JSP part" is borked. The endpoints are called, everything is fine until I return the basename of the JSP page, such as `return "info";` The method returns a `String`.

When I invoke an endpoint, I get this message:

> [...] [dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Could not resolve view with name 'info' in servlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'] with root cause
> javax.servlet.ServletException: Could not resolve view with name 'info' in servlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'

I followed "the pattern" for adding JSP support to SpringBoot (I say "the pattern" because the dozen or so sources I found all seem to quote the same example).

I'm building a JAR with Maven, looking into that jar, I don't find the JSP files, or even any of the WEB-INF directory structure, so I believe the problem is somewhere between Maven and SpringBoot's plugin.

Here are the pieces of the POM, most of the dependencies removed:

```
<packaging>jar</packaging>
...

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
...
<build>
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

The POM was built mostly from an archetype.

I'm rather ignorant about debugging Maven builds, assuming that this is a Maven problem, however, I suppose it could have something to do with the springboot plugin. I appreciate all assistance, include better resources to read than the ones that I found.

*UPDATE*
Per Qiu Zhou's comment about the , I added the following to the POM:

```
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        </resource>
    </resources>
```

and moved the JSP directory to src/main/resources/WEB-INF/jsp. The JAR file now contains this:

```
BOOT-INF/classes/WEB-INF/jsp/info.jsp
```

which seems to be correct. I no longer get the dispatcherServlet message (see above), however, when I curl the site, this is what I get:

```
% curl localhost:8099/info
{"timestamp":"2020-09-01T17:22:28.413+00:00","status":404,"error":"Not Found","message":"","path":"/info"}
```

The controller code is this:

```
@Controller
public class SimpleController {
   @GetMapping("/info")
   public String info() {
      return "info";
  }
}
```

I remain perplexed -- Is the JAR built correctly??
Thanks

Comment: Change packaging to `war` instead of `jar`

Comment: All of the instructions I found state to package SpringBoot as a JAR.

Comment: @khmarbaise - Sir (ma'am?), thank you -- I stand by my first response as being correct (that is what I had found), however, I stumbled upon this page: https://www.surasint.com/spring-boot-jsp/ and it says that if you package as a JAR, you'll get 404 when looking for the JSP files. I then packaged as a WAR, and POOF! it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

khmarbaise provided a solution in his comment - which was to package the JAR as a WAR. I waited for him to post an answer v. a comment, but its been quite a while, so I will answer on his behalf.

Answer (score 1):

You are not specifying the version of the plugin you wish to use. Depending on the version you might need to configure the plugin to add the resources directory to the application classpath by adding the following to the plugin configuration

```
<configuration>
    <addResources>true</addResources>
</configuration>
```

This enables hot reloading of resources, but what is actually recommended now for this and other development features is adding spring dev tools dependency.

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.3.RELEASE</version>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

You can learn more about it by reading the plugin docs.
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/reference/html/#run

Comment: Thanks for the response. I set the plugin version to 2.3.3.RELEASE and added the configuration element, also added the devtools dependency. Still, nothing is added to the JAR, its very puzzling.

Answer (score 0):

try following steps:

1、include `jstl` dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

2、put your jsp files in `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jsp` directory. (manually create it if does not exist)

3、set view prefix in `application.properties` or `application.yml`:

```
   spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/jsp/
   spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
```

4、specify where jsp files should be in output, put following config in `pom.xml`(based on the your config):

```
<packaging>jar</packaging>
...

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
...
<build>
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>


    <resources>
      <resource>
          <directory>src/main/webapp</directory>
          <targetPath>META-INF/resources</targetPath>
          <includes>
               <include>**/**</include>
          </includes>
          <filtering>false</filtering>
      </resource>
      <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
      </resource>
   </resources>

 </build>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I already have #1, #2, and #3 as part of that  example that I found everywhere. Where do I put the <resource> you cite in #4?

Comment: @user3481644 just edited my answer, you can see where to put that.

Comment: Thanks, I added the second resources block and moved the JSP folder to src/main/resources/WEB-INF/jsp. I now get this in the JAR: "BOOT-INF/classes/WEB-INF/jsp/info.jsp", which seems to be correct, WEB-INF is in the classpath and I've had spring.mvc.view.* configured as you have shown. I no longer get the original error message, I'll update the original post.

Comment: @user3481644 Good to hear that, now since you put JSP folder to `src/main/resources/WEB-INF/jsp` which is not exactly the location I said in my answer, you need to first set `spring.resources.static-location=classpath:WEB-INF/` in your `application.properties or application.yml`, then change view prefix to `spring.mvc.view.prefix=jsp/`.

Comment: @user3481644 also the `404 not found` error is probably because the request didn't even get to `info` method in SimpleController,  the right URL to visit should be `http://your-domain:server.port/server.servlet.context-path/info`, debug to see if you get that right.

Comment: @qui zhou - I misspoke - I did not move the JSP folder, I copied it, so there is a WEB-INF/jsp in both locations, but that should only affect from where those files are picked up when building the JAR, hence my emphasis on what I found in the JAR. The endpoint is getting called - I added a message that is printed. That static-location entry caused springboot to fail: "Reason: The elements [spring.resources.static-location] were left unbound."

Comment: @user3481644 To solve this problem "Reason: The elements [spring.resources.static-location] were left unbound." ,  you shouldn't specify the version for `spring-boot-devtools`, or just remove `spring-boot-devtools` dependency from your pom.xml.